# Validate time and allow negative values

Tags: regex, time

I use this regex to validate time entries, e.g. **08:34** - this is a valid time, 
negative time e.g. **-08:54** is not valid with this regEx.
Actually I don't know how to extend this regex in order to make also negative times valid:

```
var regex_time =/^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^-?([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

To get a positive/negative valid 24h format. If you don't need to limit the user to 24h format, use:

```
^-?(\d+):([0-5]\d)$
```

The question mark is a quantifier that means 0 to 1 of previous item.

Comment: Thanks a lot - it almost works, but **-01:30** does not work.

Comment: @user3318489: What do you mean by "does not work"? Show us your code.

Comment: @user3318489 the regex [works](https://regex101.com/r/TTzvCN/1). Maybe your implementation has a bug, could you share it?